# Cannot pass an array in request body using Api Gateway

Tags: json, rest, api-gateway

I have an API with PUT method in AWS Api Gateway. I'm passing an object in Request Body with content type **application/json**

```
{
  "uuid": "i_1",
  "insiderName": "Sam Keys",
  "profileImage": "https://do6gbw1x8hs3.cloudfront.net/spree/cover_images/53977/default/400.jpg",
  "gender": "Female",
  "fullDescription": "This is the full description",
  "shortDescription": "This is the short description",
  "tribes": ["Adventurer"]
}
```

I'm passing a `key` called tribes and a value as an array. But I'm getting this error:

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'A\' (code 65)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: [B@5d62dfa1; line: 8, column: 17]"}
```

I believe the error is caused by the array in the request body

Comment: I don't know what's the problem with the code, but to workaround the error, have you tried to place the array into an object with a key?

Answer (score 0):

We had same problem ,I added a work around by changing the array of strings into pipe separated  single string and converted back to array of string after the Json is parsed on the API .

```
        IDictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>> reportObject in dictionary)
        {
            // do something with entry.Value or entry.Key
            dictionary[entry.Key] = string.Join("|", reportObject.Value.Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x)));
        }
```